# Can't add views in EF with npgsql

Tags: visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I am trying to add views to an EF model, but the operation fails without any errors.
It just ignores all the views I check in the "Update Model from Database".
I even tried to create a very simple view that just contains 1 string column..
Tables do get added.
I am using VS2015 and NpgsqlDdexProvider-3.1.0 + npgsql 3.1.9
Not sure what other information might be useful.

Comment: Did some more digging, here is one error I see: `Error 6013: The table/view 'webcheckout.public.person_view' does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been excluded. To use the entity, you will need to review your schema, add the correct keys, and uncomment it.` I thought that views can't have primary keys.